# How to load ar.js custom image marker from assets folder in android webview

Tags: ar.js

I am trying to make a project in android webview of Image Tracking AR with A-Frame and AR.js following the example on the blog link https://aframe.io/blog/arjs3/. I am able to track marker and display 3d from server urls.
As a second step, I am trying to place the image markers in assets folder and load it from there. I have tried various ways to give the file path but none of it works, the page shows loading. This is the way I try to give the marker path.
I have made a folder inside assets and kept the three files, iset,fset and fset3 there. The html file is placed in asset folder parallel to the image folder.

```
    <a-nft
        type="nft"
        url="file:///android_asset/Waffy/Waffy"
        crossorigin ="anonymous"
        smooth="true"
        smoothCount="10"
        smoothTolerance=".01"
        smoothThreshold="5"
>
```

How can I access the custom image from the asset folder? I have been stuck on the issue for two days now.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your android_asset folder is in the same directory as the HTML file, this should work:

```
<a-nft
    type="nft"
    url="./android_asset/Waffy/Waffy"
    crossorigin ="anonymous"
    smooth="true"
    smoothCount="10"
    smoothTolerance=".01"
    smoothThreshold="5">
```